# Is there any way or workaround to schedule Amazon Mechanical Turk HITs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I need a specific HIT to run every Friday morning. Is there any way to do this or any workaround with an external platform (IFTTT, zapier both don't work) to do this? It seems to me like a very fundamental feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I figured out how to use Zapier with MTurk. If you are on a paid plan you can leverage the AWS Lambda app to trigger some code that will create a HIT on MTurk. To do this you need an AWS account that's linked to your MTurk account. Once you have that you can create a Lambda function that contains the following code for creating a HIT on MTurk:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    ###################################
    # Step 1: Create a client
    ###################################
    endpoint = "https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    mturk = boto3.client(
    service_name='mturk',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    endpoint_url=endpoint)

    ###################################
    # Step 2: Define the task
    ###################################
    html = '''
        <**********************************
        My task HTML
        ***********************************>
    '''.format(event['<my parameter>'])

    question_xml = '''
    <HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
    <HTMLContent><![CDATA[{}]]></HTMLContent>
    <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
    </HTMLQuestion>'''.format(html)

    task_attributes = {
    'MaxAssignments': 3,
    'LifetimeInSeconds': 60 * 60 * 5, # Stay active for 5 hours
    'AssignmentDurationInSeconds': 60 * 10, # Workers have 10 minutes to respond
    'Reward': '0.03',
    'Title': '<Task title>',
    'Keywords': '<keywords>',
    'Description': '<Task description>'
    }

    ###################################
    # Step 3: Create the HIT
    ###################################
    response = mturk.create_hit(
    **task_attributes,
    Question=question_xml
    )
    hit_type_id = response['HIT']['HITTypeId']
    print('Created HIT {} in HITType {}'.format(response['HIT']['HITId'], hit_type_id))
```

Note you'll need to give the role your Lambda is using access to MTurk. From there you can create an IAM user for Zapier to use when calling your Lambda and link it to your Zapier account. Now you can setup your Action to call that Lambda function with whatever parameters you want to pass in the event.

If you want to get the results of the HIT back into your Zap it will be more complicated because Zapier isn't well suited to the asynchronous nature of MTurk HITs. I've put together a blog post on how to do this below:
https://www.daveschultzconsulting.com/2019/07/18/using-mturk-with-zapier/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature in the MTurk API to accomplish scheduled launch of HITs. It must be done through custom programming.

If you are looking for a turn-key solution, scheduling can be done via [TurkPrime](https://www.turkprime.com/LaunchedSurvey/PreviewMTurkPanelsToolkit) using the Scheduled Launch Time found in tab 5 (Setup Hit and Payments)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is closer to what I need, but it seems like TurkPrime does not offer recurring schedules. I would like it to happen every week but only set up once :)

Comment: @janjackson You can request that using their Suggestion Box (https://feedback.turkprime.com/feature-requests)